# Is it possible to use jQuery inside of Vaadin framework?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, vaadin

As Vaadin is a Java web application framework, so is it possible to insert the jQuery javascript snippet in the Vaadin Java code?

Comment: I don't see why not, but I don't see why you would want to... surely the framework allows for separated view and controller?

Comment: The framework provides the custom component to use the native js code. However, while I tried some complex js code, there is probably nothing   happened. That is why I asked such question.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is.

Create your own ApplicationServlet extending class like this:

```
public class MyApplicationServlet extends ApplicationServlet {

    @Override
    protected void writeAjaxPageHtmlVaadinScripts(Window window,
            String themeName, Application application, BufferedWriter page,
            String appUrl, String themeUri, String appId,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {

        page.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
        page.write("//<![CDATA[\n");
        page.write("document.write(\"<script language='javascript' src='./jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'><\\/script>\");\n");
        page.write("//]]>\n</script>\n");

        super.writeAjaxPageHtmlVaadinScripts(window, themeName, application,
            page, appUrl, themeUri, appId, request);
    }
}
```

Then replace the Vaadin servlet in your web.xml (the default is `com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet`):

```
<servlet-class>com.example.MyApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
```

You can then make jQuery calls in your code by calling:

```
MyApplication.getMainWindow().executeJavascript(jQueryString);
```

Comment: As I tried, the code of this line: MyApplication.getMainWindow().executeJavascript(jQueryString);may only work for some simple javascript code. It seems not quite to support more complex js code.

Comment: I don't know jQuery that well, but at least in my Vaadin application it is used by Invient charts (based on Highcharts). Would it work for you if you declared your jQuery stuff in a js file, put it in the page headers (like jQuery.js) and called your functions with executeJavascript? And furthermore, did you check (w/ firebug or similar) that jQuery library was successfully loaded?

Comment: I am also using Invient Charts. It works well for me. I need jQuery to  implement some other components that Vaadin does not provide. The question how to communicate from the Vaadin Server side with the Client side.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "The question how to communicate from the Vaadin Server side with the Client side." ?

Comment: @ miq, I am wanting to use the native js code from the server side, such as some jquery ui component, with out to implement a vaadin custom component.

Comment: It just became easier; in Vaadin 7 you can use the JavaScript class to do this. See: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.javascript.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use the @JavaScript and @StyleSheet annotations

```
@StyleSheet({
                /*
                 * JQuery UI
                 */
                "vaadin://jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css",
})

@JavaScript({   
                /*
                 * JQuery
                 */
                "vaadin://jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js",

                /*
                 * JQuery UI 
                 */
                "vaadin://jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js",
})

public class MyUI extends UI {
 ...
}
```

For execution:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("...javascript code here...")
```

Be careful with larger scripts. Adding javascript via the vaadin annotation has very poor performance. Better inject the script in the html header manually.

Comment: Where do the files (e.g. `/jquery/...`) go to? In which folder in the project?

Comment: Files goes into the "VAADIN" folder of the application which can be accessed by the "vaadin://"url

Answer (score 3):

One more customizing for ApplicationServlet:

```
public class VaadinApplicationServlet extends ApplicationServlet {

    @Override
    protected void writeAjaxPageHtmlHeader(BufferedWriter page, String title, String themeUri, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        page.write("<script language='javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>");
        super.writeAjaxPageHtmlHeader(page, title, themeUri, request);
    }

}
```