# How to use third-party javascript libraries with vaadin 6?

Tags: java, vaadin, jointjs

I am using `Vaadin 6.7.8` and want to use `JointJs`. However couldn't find a way to use 3rd party javascript libraries along with Vaadin 6. Would really appreciate any help.

Is it a drawback of using Vaadin? I hope not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

vaadin 7 allows you directly to do it.
In vaadin 6 you have a little bit more to do, but it also works.

Look here for the different solutions with vaadin 6

[Is it possible to use jQuery inside of Vaadin framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303534/is-is-possible-to-use-jquery-inside-of-vaadin-framework)

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin 7 you can use @JavaScript annotation to include third-party JS libraries as you can see here in this sample

```
#!java
import com.vaadin.annotations.*;

@JavaScript({"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js", "jquery.flot.js", "flot_connector.js"})
public class Flot extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {
    public void addSeries(double... points) {
        List<List<Double>> pointList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            pointList.add(Arrays.asList(Double.valueOf(i),
                    Double.valueOf(points[i])));
        }

        getState().series.add(pointList);
    }

    @Override
    public FlotState getState() {
        return (FlotState) super.getState();
    }
}
```

Inside your Vaadin code, you can call / execute arbitrary JS code as follow:

```
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(" your CUSTOM JS CODE GOES HERE");
```

But i dont know if this works on Vaadin 6. You can upgrade to Vaadin 7 and be happy =)

Comment: unfortunately it is impossible :(

Comment: you still have many option including: creating custom widgets, creating a custon theme or even using page.write( customHtmlAndJsCode). And if someday you migrate to Vaadin 7, this link may help you: http://www.streamhead.com/upgrading-vaadin-7/