# Vaadin 7 : How to import JS files from custom path?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am using **Vaadin-7** and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303534/is-is-possible-to-use-jquery-inside-of-vaadin-framework/9308870#9308870) answer was not fix for me .

I am trying to import my js file under `myproject/WebContent/js/test.js` . I used `@JavaScript` in my UI class as below..

```
@Theme("myTheme")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Title("VaadinTest")
@JavaScript("js/test.js")
public class VaadinTest extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);
}
}
```

But I got `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/myproject/APP/PUBLISHED/js/test.js"` error log in my firebug console.

So , how can I import js files from my custom directories ?

> **PS:** Please don't be force me to create *APP/PUBLISHED/* directory manually ! Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `app://`:

```
@JavaScript({ "app://js/test.js" })
```

or use:

```
@JavaScript({ "vaadin://js/test.js" })
```

Generated url inside VAADIN folder:

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/VAADIN/js/test.js
```

Comment: do you mean I need to put my js file under `WebContent/VAADIN/` folder ?

Comment: can you support me more suggestions about using `vaadin://` ?

Comment: Yes , thank you . After I move my js files to under **VAADIN** folder , it is fine. But my oringinal post was to import custom path.

Answer (score 3):

the file you refer to must be reachable by the classloader relative to the package you are using it in.  according to your example, lets say your package of `VaadinTest` is `com.example.app` and you want to access it as `js/test.js` you have to put it in the directory `com/example/app/js/test.js` in a "root" for the classloader to find it (e.g. `src/main/java,groovy` or where resources are loaded from in your config).