# Vaadin: adding a custom javascript to bootstrap page

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to add jquery to bootstrap page of my vaadin application. I added following in my custom `Servlet` class

```
@Override
public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException {
    event.getSession().addBootstrapListener(new BootstrapListener() {
        @Override
        public void modifyBootstrapPage(BootstrapPageResponse response) {
            //Jquery is necessary for open in new window button
            String contextPath = event.getRequest().getContextPath();
            response.getDocument().head().prependElement("script").attr("type", "text/javascript").attr("src", contextPath + "/VAADIN/js/jquery.min.js");
            response.getDocument().head().prependElement("script").attr("type", "text/javascript").attr("src", contextPath + "/VAADIN/js/jquery-ui.js");
        }

        @Override
        public void modifyBootstrapFragment(BootstrapFragmentResponse response) {
        }
    });
}
```

This code sometimes throws a null pointer exception in `event.getRequest().getContextPath();`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getServletContext(Request.java:1598) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getContextPath(Request.java:1915) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getContextPath(RequestFacade.java:783) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getContextPath(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:150) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
at com.mycompany.MyServlet$1.modifyBootstrapPage(YaanServlet.java:56) ~[web-yaan-ui-base-1.3.39.jar:?]
```

What is the correct way to get the context path in this situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303534/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-inside-of-vaadin-framework/25155182#25155182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler way would be to use the @JavsScript annotation on your UI class

```
package com.company.mine;
@JavaScript({"jquery.min.js","jquery-ui.js"})
public class YourUI extends UI 
{

}
```

You will then need to put the two javascript files into a folder matching the class of YourUI. I use maven so it need to be in src/main/resources/com/company/mine/jquery.min.js