# What is the Vaadin 8 way of adding code to the html head tag?

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin8

[Other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12074183/1124509) suggest overriding `ApplicationServlet.writeAjaxPageHtmlHeader`, but I cannot find those classes and methods in Vaadin 8.

I cannot find anything similar in `com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet` or `com.vaadin.ui.UI`.

There is the `@JavaScript` annotation, but if I put that on my UI class, the script would be loaded for every page of my application. I need it only on one specific page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initial HTML page is called bootstrap page in Vaadin. There is some documentation that hints you to right direction in [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/application-structure/tutorial-bootstrap.html).

In Vaadin 8, you need to add BootstrapListener to session. You can get created sessions by adding SessionInitListener in VaadinServlet.

**Register Session**

This example is using Vaadin with Spring Boot but the same principle applies when not using Spring Boot.

```
@Component("vaadinServlet")
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "BootstrapVaadinServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = BoostrapUi.class, productionMode = false)
public class BootstrapVaadinServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BootstrapVaadinServlet.class);
    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(this::addBoostrapListenerOnSessionInit);
    }

    private void addBoostrapListenerOnSessionInit(SessionInitEvent sessionInitEvent) {
        sessionInitEvent.getSession().addBootstrapListener(new AppBootstrapListener());
    }
}
```

**Implement html head tag modification**

```
public class AppBootstrapListener implements BootstrapListener {
    @Override
    public void modifyBootstrapFragment(BootstrapFragmentResponse bootstrapFragmentResponse) {

    }

    @Override
    public void modifyBootstrapPage(BootstrapPageResponse res) {
        Elements headTags = res.getDocument().getElementsByTag("head");
        Element head = headTags.get(0);
        head.appendChild(metaExample(res.getDocument()));
    }

    private Node metaExample(Document document) {
        Element meta = document.createElement("meta");
        meta.attr("author", "Me");
        return meta;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using add-on is ok, try [HeaderTags](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/headertags)

> Overview
>
> Using this add-on, you can define tags to add to the host page by
>   adding annotation to your UI class.

Sample from add ons usage example

```
@MetaTags({
   // Replaces the Vaadin X-UA-Compatible header
   @Meta(httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible", content = "hello"),
   @Meta(name = "test", content = "test") })

// And showing how to create a link tag as well
@Link(rel = "foobar", href = "about:blank")
public class DemoUI extends UI {
    ...
}
```